# XmlSerializer - linq-to-sql - A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to use XmlSerializer in my linq-to-sql MVC2 webapp to store complex objects in a database. I've been googling and experimenting for the past 3 days and cannot get past this circular reference error. I've read many articles with suggestions on how to solve this, and none of them have worked for me. I have especially been trying this tactic because LOTS of related articles link back to this one. So this article seems to be emerging as a popular approach:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Sep/02/LINQ-to-SQL-and-Serialization

I have tried to implement this suggested fix for circular reference problems in linq-to-sql and it just doesn’t work. I have triple/quadruple checked that I’m changing ALL child property access modifiers to Internal, but to no avail. I always get the circular reference error no matter what I do. I recompile after each change of course. I make sure to leave the Parent property access modifier to public.

Based on another article I read, I also tried attributing all EntitySet with this:
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]

That didn't work for me either--same error.

I’m not using WCF – just linq to sql in a webapp with MVC2. I can serialize non-linq-to-sql objects without a problem, regardless of complexity.

Here is my serializer function:

```
private static string SerializeToString(object obj)
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); 

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), "");
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
```

If anyone has thoughts on this I would love to hear.

Comment: Can you give some indication of what the model looks like here? In particular the association properties?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The circular reference occurs when you have to objects which references each other. These kind of references are not supported by the serializer.

For example:

```
public class Object1
{
    public Object2 SecondObject { get; set; } 
}


public class Object2
{
    public Object1 FirstObject { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: It is linq-to-sql that puts in circular references all over the place automatically. As I mentioned in my post, setting the Internal is supposed to prevent that, but apparently it doesn't. I'm not manually creating classes that reference each other. So this doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

Espen Burod is right. Do not directly serialize your entites. Instead, create a data transfer model and serialize that one. You can map between the two using AutoMapper.

Comment: We ending up massively refactoring the app and we no longer store objects. That was fun. Thanks all. :-)